# Loopback acl admin role is not applying on Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, authentication, loopback

I was wondering if somebody can help me out in this , I am unable to find why my 'admin' role is not working in loopback 3.x , I am trying the below codes :

**script.js** - For Creating admin roles in postgres db, this correctly creates the Roles and Mapping

```
module.exports = function (app) {
var User = app.models.User;
var Role = app.models.Role;
var RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;

  User.create([
  {username: 'Test', email: 'test@gmail.com', password: 'test'},
], function(err, users) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Created users:', users);
  //create the admin role
  Role.create({
    name: 'admin'
  }, function(err, role) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Created role:', role);
    role.principals.create({
      principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
      principalId: users[0].id
    }, function(err, principal) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Created principal:', principal);
    }); 
  });
});
}
```

Then in **authentication.js** -

```
server.enableAuth({ datasource: 'ds' });
```

In the **testModel.json** , *acls* as follows :

```
"acls": [
{
  "accessType": "WRITE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW"
}
]
```

**NOTE** - I want to give WRITE Permissions to ADMIN only.

But still the **POST** api of this model is accessible to all, Please correct me where I am wrong!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer by applying the acls in the following manner :

```
 "acls": [
{
  "accessType": "WRITE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
},
{
  "accessType": "WRITE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW"
}
],
```

I simply Restricted all the Users first and then gave permissions to **Admin** only!

This way it worked for me, You can correct me if theirs some better way :)